# Update on Save vs Manual Update Which Is Most Reliable In Magento Indexing

Tags: catalog, indexing

In indexing there is two option update on save and manual update.
Which one is good for big catalog?
Basically I want to know that if I save my product product on save then it's good or not.

Because some time on manual indexing I got "Error : 500 Internal Server Error".
So if any body can explain then please.

Comment: are you getting 500 error when you kept "manual indexing".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update on save** will fire some (indexing related) events after a product is saved, so a full reindex won't be necessary after product updates. **Manual** mode won't fire anything, so product updates will run faster, but you'll need to reindex everything in order to see some changes in frontend

Note that "product updates" does mean some frontend processes too, not only backoffice. For instance, depending by your site configuration, some stock events could be fired during checkout, making it slower if indexes are **Update on save**

When dealing with a big catalog, the usual method is to have all indexes in manual mode, and then reindex everything via cron every X hours

Comment: Nice answer, Thanks for sharing your knowledge ,  +1 from me :-)

Comment: When "Update on Save" is enabled, does it reindex all products or just the 1 product?

Answer (score 0):

`update on save` is better , it will improve the speed of the site. but at the time of importing products , if you keep "Manual index" and than importing of products is much faster , but after uploading you need to change to `update on save`