# Magento does not load new content

Tags: magento2, cache

0
down vote
favorite

I am new in magento and I need your help with the following:

I have a Magento store installed that is working "Fine", but when I add new products or any content on my store, this can´t showed automaticly in the front of store, only in my admin display, then I have to run the command to index and after doing this, all is showing on front

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

The problem is that the content manager from this website is not a developer, is a secretary and she does not know about programming

How to make that the content loaded on website , be automatically loaded on the front?

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses a complex system of indices and flat tables to improve shop performance. While it really helps regarding loading speed, this architecture comes with some disadvantages: All these flat tables and indices have to be generated - either manually, or automatically.

One option would be, to run the indexer via **cron job**. Cron jobs are basically a way to execute scripts automatically on specified, scheduled times. This is, how to configure cron jobs properly in Magento:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

You could also create your own cron job just for the indexing, if you feel more comfortable doing so.

However, cron jobs are not offered by all hosting providers. You might need to  move to another web hosting provider or upgrade your hosting package in order to use them, and you might need to be able to get along with the command line.

A second choice would be the feature *update on save*, which is explained here: [Update on Save vs Manual Update Which Is Most Reliable In Magento Indexing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110919/update-on-save-vs-manual-update-which-is-most-reliable-in-magento-indexing) and here [Reindexing : When do you use 'Update on schedule' or 'update on save'?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183460/reindexing-when-do-you-use-update-on-schedule-or-update-on-save)

As an alternative, you might think about to grant the secretary more access. Turning off the Magento cache might be another option, but I do not know if it helps in your case, and it usually strongly decreases the speed of your shop.